# How to calculate avg of column inside query and display it

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

How can I select all products, their name, average star rating, and most recent rating date? The results should be in descending order of average star rating.
thats what i did so far

```
SELECT product_name, AVG(rating_stars)
FROM rating
INNER JOIN product
ORDER BY AVG(rating_stars) DESC
```

and that's the database

```
CREATE TABLE product
(
    prod_id varchar(15),
    product_name varchar(30),
    product_price double precision,
    product_manufacturer varchar(30),
    PRIMARY KEY (prod_id)
)

CREATE TABLE customer
(
    cust_id varchar(15),
    customer_name varchar (30),
    customer_adress varchar (30),
    PRIMARY KEY (cust_id)
)

CREATE TABLE rating
(
    prod_id,
    cust_id,
    rating_date date not null,
    rating_stars int (5),

    PRIMARY KEY (rating_date),
    FOREIGN KEY (prod_id) REFERENCES Products(prod_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (cust_id) REFERENCES customer(cust_id)
)

CREATE TABLE sale
(
    sale_id,
    prod_id,
    cust_id,
    sale_quantity int,
    sale_cost double precision,

    PRIMARY KEY (sale_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (prod_id) REFERENCES Products(prod_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (cust_id) REFERENCES customer(cust_id)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by and max

```
SELECT product_name, AVG(rating_stars),  max(rating_date)
FROM rating
INNER JOIN product on rating.prod_id = product.prod_id 
GROUP BY product_name
ORDER BY AVG(rating_stars) DESC
```

Comment: its telling me no results found

Comment: Are you sure you have valid data in your tables??   update your question add  a proper data sample and  the expcted  resul as tabular text